# os.walk in Python is returning an empty list

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `os.walk` to return a list of .xlsx files from a directory, but it's returning an empty list.

```
import os
import pathlib

working_directory = 'N:/files path'

def find_filenames(path, suffix):
# First save all filenames in a list: file_list:
    file_list = []
    # Gets a list of all validation xlsx files in the folder:
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(suffix):
                # save filesnames in file_list: 
                file_list.append(file)
            return file_list
        
print(find_filenames(pathlib.Path(working_directory), '.xlsx')
```

It's printing this:

```
[]
```

When it should look like this:

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: your `return` statement is indented incorrectly. logic is fine

Comment: The problem with the code is that the return statement returns from the loops after the very first file was checked (which in this example does not end with `.xlsx`). Like in below answer from @raspiduino, the return needs to be done after looping over all files. You need to fix the indentation.

Comment: This is really minor but you have a missing closing parenthesis on that print statement.

Comment: @schilli that's right :)

Comment: @astrochun yeah there are only 2 ')' while there are 3 '('. But why it still work?

Comment: Huh. It shouldn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should it be:

```
import os
import pathlib

working_directory = 'N:/files path'

def find_filenames(path, suffix):
# First save all filenames in a list: file_list:
    file_list = []
    # Gets a list of all validation xlsx files in the folder:
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(suffix):
                # save filesnames in file_list: 
                file_list.append(file)
    return file_list
```

The problem is you have put the `return` in wrong place. If you put like the code in your question and if the first file is not end with `.xlsx`, it will directly return `[]`!

Comment: Works now! I don't know how I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, indentation problem. I hate those indentation bugs :)

Answer (score 3):

While the above answer is correct and is the simplest fix, I wanted to recommend a suggestion. You're importing `pathlib`, which already has built-in recursive `glob`-ing. As such, you can simplify your code if your expectation is a Path object for path:

```
import pathlib

working_directory = 'N:/files path'

def find_filenames(path: pathlib.Path, suffix: str):
    return list(path.rglob('*'+suffix))


print(find_filenames(pathlib.Path(working_directory), '.xlsx'))
```

`rglob` method will do recursive globbing here! Also, you would not need to import `os` for this snippet of code.

Comment: Wow man that's a wonderful answer. From that I not only know about the `path.rglob` method but also how to set the type of the function parameter :)

Comment: @raspiduino, your answer is the easiest fix for the OP. Just thought this could be helpful for other users. You can find more information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) about type hints/annotation.

Comment: I could edit this answer to ensure that the suffix does not require the `.`.